# Pandas version 0.22.0 - drop_duplicates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep'

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I am trying to drop duplicates in my dataframe using drop_duplicates(subset=[''], keep=False). Apparently it is working just okay in my Jupyter Notebook but when I am trying to executing through terminal as .py file I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/source/fork/PySpark_Analytics/Notebooks/Krish/beryllium_pandas.py", line 54, in <module>
    dffsamelname = dffsameflname.drop_duplicates(subset=['INDIVIDUAL_LASTNAME'], keep=False)

File "/var/webeng/opensource/aetna-anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: drop_duplicates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep'
```

Checked that the pandas version is >0.18 as keep = false was introduced then.

```
# Trying to drop both the records with same last name
dffsamelname = dffsameflname.drop_duplicates(subset=['INDIVIDUAL_LASTNAME'], keep=False)
```

I want to drop both the records being dropped. Hence keep=false is necessary.

It just works fine if I remove the keep=false.

Comment: What is the output of `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: @Erfan: 0.22.0 it is this

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your object is not a native pandas dataframe but instead a pyspark dataframe. 
From this http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop_duplicates it seems that subset is only argument accepted. Can you add your imports and the lines where you create the dataframe.

Comment: I have the data frame converted toPandas() before I do this operation.

Comment: import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext,SQLContext,functions
from datetime import date, timedelta
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,explode
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Set up Spark Session
sqlSession = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("Beryllium Model")\
        .enableHiveSupport()\
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")\
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")\
        .getOrCreate()

Comment: Just checking that you assigned toPandas() to something as it is not an in-place function

Comment: @NicholasStevens then how would you tell pyspark to keep the records where INDIVIDUAL_LASTNAME = false?